# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod fails with 401 status

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am writing jenkins pipelinescript to call a rest service through powershell.

```
username = "myusername"
passwor = "mypwd"
uri="myresturl"
fileName="myfilePath"


withEnv(["resturi=${uri}","filePath=${fileName}", "uid=${username}", "passwordd=${passwor}"]) 
{

    powershell '''

            $pwd = $Env:passwordd | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force          

            $credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Env:uid, $pwd

            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Env:resturi  -Method Post -InFile $Env:filePath -Credential $credential

            '''
            }
```

When I run the above script, it is getting failed with the following error:

```
powershell.exe : Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.At At C:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\ApigeeNew@tmp\durable-8134c670\powershellWrapper.ps1:5 char:3
+   & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Fi ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invoke-RestMeth...nauthorized.At     :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

C:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\ApigeeNew@tmp\durable-8134c670\powershellScript.ps1:

17 char:7

+             Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Env:resturi  -Method Post -InFile ...

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 

   pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 

   ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

**I am using correct username and password and the same functionality is working fine through cUrl script. Powershell version is 5.0.**

**Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in the above script.**

**My cUrl script:**
 `withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'prasad', usernameVariable:'pcfUserName', passwordVariable: 'pcfPassword']]) 
         {
            createProxyURL = env.APIGEE_ENV_URL + '/apis?action=import&name=' + proxyName + '&validate=true'
            scriptString = "curl -X POST -u ${pcfUserName}:${pcfPassword} -F  file=@" + apiProxyZip + "  \"" + createProxyURL + "\" "
}`

credentialsId:'prasad' --> 'prasad' points to Jenkins->Credentials

Comment: You're passing your credentials wrong.  It's expecting a header, but all you're doing is invoking the request as a different user.

Comment: username = "myusername", passwor = "mypwd"  are not my original username/password. Just to post my question here, I gave some dummy values.

Comment: Post your existing curl call in your question (obfuscated) so help can be directed

Comment: I have added the cUrl script to the question.